# Is it possible to float IFrame out of the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, drag-and-drop, draggable

I wanted to know if it is possible to float IFrame out of the browser?
Is it possible to drag the IFrame outside of the browser?

the idea is that my html\js application is like a taskbar and I want that the Iframes will be able to be drag on the top of another programs outside my browser.

thanks,
Dor.

Comment: I'm confused: do you want to open the iframe in a new browser tab, or in a new browser window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only application I have seen that can do that is [AIR](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappsflex/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7d85.html). That said, you can do [edge detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293393/reposition-drop-down-menu-if-near-edge-of-window) and open the iframe content in a new window when it hits the edge if you know the URL

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/dEemD/)
and accompanying [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/dEemD/show) - as always window.open assumes you allow popups from the site

using jQuery UI draggable:

```js
$("#container").draggable({
  drag: function(event, ui) {
    var offsetXPos = parseInt( ui.offset.left );
    var offsetYPos = parseInt( ui.offset.top );
    $("#coord").text(offsetXPos+'x'+offsetYPos);
    if (offsetXPos===0 || offsetYPos===0) { // be careful with <= since it may trigger many windows
      $("#container").hide();
      window.open('http://msn.com','_blank');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="handle">Drag me <span id="coord"></span></div>
    <iframe src="http://msn.com/" frameborder=no></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
#container { left:100px; top:100px; width:500px }
#handle { border:1px solid black; height:40px, width:100%; background-color:lightblue; cursor:move; pointer:move}
iframe { width:100%; border:0 }
```

Comment: Thanks, can you explain a little more? maybe links to examples?

Comment: Thanks again, Your demo only let me drag an item inside the browser, I want it to get out of the browser. the idea is that my html\js application is like a taskbar and I want that the Iframes will be able to be drag on the top of another programs outside my browser.

Comment: The new requirement cannot be satisfied with javascript or plain client coding - you cannot hold on to the object you are dragging. My demo even opens a new TAB in my browser rather than a new window since those are my settings of that browser which you cannot override.

Comment: In Google Chrome, this demo appears to redirect the current tab to msn.com instead of opening the iframe in a new window.

Comment: MSN has put framebuster code in since I wrote the code. I will change to a frameable site

Answer (score 2):

No but you could add javascript to launch a popup (which would reload the iframe from the server) and delete the iframe from the current document.